# Popup gallery when click on thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: slider i want to make]

Is there some plugin for slider like this? Or can someone tell me how to make this? Want, when click on last box, to open modal slider with all these pictures; if click on displayed picture (like img1, img2...img6) open slider with clicked img in focus.
Want to show just 6 imgs, for example, like attached img, and rest to bi in last box like "+4 more". Is there something that count rest of imgs like this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at a plugin like Owl Carousel, this should give you a great place to start.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/